# Max requests AWS Application load balancer can handle concurrently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Searching for limitations of AWS Application Load Balancer in terms of max requests it can handle concurrently. It exclusively mentions Network Load balancer can handle millions of requests but no mention about ALB. The AWS docs mention about qoutas on rules, listeners, target groups only. Any documentation would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Application load balancer scale with demand. New ALBs are added using CNAMES in the background, which means that there is virtually no limit.

Network load balancers on the other hand use static ip addresses, which means that scaling us more difficult, hence the explicit mention in the documentation.